# Specify index document collection sorting

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

Let's imagine I have the following index definition:

```
public class LastSuspensions: AbstractIndexCreationTask<Casino, LastSuspensions.ReduceResult>
    {
        public class ReduceResult
        {
            public string CityId { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
            public string CasinoId { get; set; }
            public IList<Exemption> Exemptions { get; set; }
        }

        public LastSuspensions()
        {
            Map = casinos => from casino in casinos
                             from suspension in casino.Suspensions
                             select new { CityId = casino.CityId, DateTime = suspension.DateTime, CasinoId = casino.Id, Exemptions = suspension.Exemptions };

            Store(x => x.CityId, FieldStorage.Yes);
            Store(x => x.DateTime, FieldStorage.Yes);
            Store(x => x.CasinoId, FieldStorage.Yes);
            Store(x => x.Exemptions, FieldStorage.Yes);
        }
```

Is there any way to specify I want to get Exemptions collection to be sorted by one of its properties?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call Store on those fields.
And since you are going to pull the entire exceptions collection out, as part of loading the document, there is no real additional cost of doing the sorting on the client.

Comment: There is some cost if collection is big, so I want to know whether it is possible to make it on the server

Answer (score 0):

Your *Exemption* class should implement IComparable interface. The IComparable interface defines the CompareTo(T) method, which determines the sort order of instances of the implementing type. A sample can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) as well as [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/GenericListSort.aspx).

I hope this is helpful.

Greetings,
Evgenia

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think your answer somehow relates to my question